# Script Editor in iCloud

Tags: icloud, applescript

When I open Script Editor (by opening Finder, then clicking on Applications -> Utilities -> Script Editor) the following window shows.

[image: ScriptEditor]

As can be seen both in the top panel as well as in the side panel, Script Editor is is in the iCloud. Why is it in the iCloud? Didn't it used to be on the hard drive? Is it possible to download it to my hard drive? I tried to search for Script Editor in the App Store, but it doesn't seem to be there.

---

macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the documents container in iCloud Drive, as you're looking at File Open dialog. Each iCloud-supported app has a container for documents in iCloud Drive. The application itself is still in the Applications folder as usual.